# Background image size for Android

Tags: android

I have an image that I want to place on the background on my activity.  For the G1 I would use a background of 320x480 but with the nexus 1 the resolution is almost double that.  Should I just place the large image and make the smaller phones size down?  I am trying to keep the size of my package down as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a simple colour or a gradient, you can share the same drawable for all screen resolutions.

If it's a more complex graphic, then you should create separate images for different screen resolutions (or densities) by placing them in the [appropriate directories](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) (e.g. "drawable-nodpi", "drawable-hdpi" etc.).

Comment: OK, thanks...however, wouldn't having 2 images instead of 1 bulk up my file size?  Why not just use the the large one and let android resize? CPU is not an issue at the moment.

Comment: Well you can try it for yourself on the emulator; the graphic may well look nasty when scaled up or down. But surely your background graphic isn't that large anyway -- I wouldn't say there's any reason to worry about APK size unless it's heading towards multiple megabytes...

Answer (score 0):

A repeatable background image can be the best way to handle device resolution compatibility for simple patterns:

[How to make android app's background image repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat)