# How to make an app's background image repeat

Tags: android, image, layout

I have set a background image in my app, but the background image is small and I want it to be repeated and fill in the whole screen. What should I do?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:tileMode="repeat">
```

Answer (score 433, accepted):

Ok, here's what I've got in my app. It includes a hack to prevent `ListView`s from going black while scrolling.

**drawable/app_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/actual_pattern_image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

**values/styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="app_theme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/TransparentListView</item>
    <item name="android:expandableListViewStyle">@style/TransparentExpandableListView</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TransparentListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TransparentExpandableListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ExpandableListView">
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
//
<application android:theme="@style/app_theme">
//
```

Comment: Try with this too: android:gravity="clip_horizontal"

--- it avoid image deformation

Comment: I've tried this but saw only single tile stretched to all the screen :(

Comment: If I have a `ScrollView` and place a background to repeat on it and I have a long long list, won't I have problems with OutOfMemory exception when the `ScrollView` becomes very long?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that you should have folders drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi & drawable-ldpi, you'll need to add this backrepeat.xml file and the relevant images to each of these to allow this functionality in high, medium and low dpi (dots per inch) screen sizes.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi You only need images in those folders. XML can be placed in `drawable` (withoud `-*dpi`) folder.

Comment: Getting the error:  <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute

Answer (score 179):

There is a property in the drawable xml to do it.
android:tileMode="repeat"

See this site:
http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-tile-background-image-in-android.html

Comment: I really don't know how is this so low rated. Herd instinct? This is the native implementation of tiled background

Comment: This one works like a charm. Also this one seems like the right way to do it.

Comment: I agree that this should be the accepted answer. It's really simple and works perfectly!

Comment: +1 Only one thing must be corrected that is mentioned wrongly in the article: `you'll need to add this backrepeat.xml file and the relevant images to each of these to allow this functionality in high, medium and low dpi`. You only have to place the referenced drawables in all density buckets. The referencing XML drawable can be placed in `drawable` folder, that is enough.

Comment: This is what you call explained by a pro

Comment: This works fine if "actual_pattern_image" was a bitmap but what about the vectors?

Answer (score 72):

Here is a pure-java implementation of background image repeating:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_image);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
    bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
}
```

In this case, our background image would have to be stored in res/drawable/bg_image.png.

Comment: If I have a `ScrollView` and place a background to repeat on it and I have a long long list, won't I have problems with OutOfMemory exception when the `ScrollView` becomes very long?

Comment: Why should this not be working anymore? Depreciation means these commands should not be used anymore because they may be retired some time in the future. In API 19, this still works as @plowman suggested. Also, not BitmapDrawable is deprecated, but only some of its methods. I have edited the code above so we don't have to use deprecated methods.

Answer (score 16):

Expanding on plowman's answer, here is the non-deprecated version of changing the background image with java.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.texture);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmp);
    bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Prepared By Muhammad Mubashir.
// 26, August, 2011.
// Chnage Back Ground Image of Activity.

package com.ChangeBg_01;

import com.ChangeBg_01.R;

import android.R.color;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChangeBg_01Activity extends Activity
{
    TextView tv;
    int[] arr = new int[2];
    int i=0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        arr[0] = R.drawable.icon1;
        arr[1] = R.drawable.icon;

     // Load a background for the current screen from a drawable resource
        //getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.icon1) ;

        final Handler handler=new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                //tv.append("Hello World");
                if(i== 2){
                    i=0;            
                }

                getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(arr[i]);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                i++;
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) 
                    {
                        if(i== 2){
                            //finish();
                            i=0;
                        }
                        sleep(1000);
                        handler.post(r);
                        //i++;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


    }
}

/*android:background="#FFFFFF"*/
/*
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.layout.main);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);*/

// Now get a handle to any View contained 
// within the main layout you are using
/*        View someView = (View)findViewById(R.layout.main);

// Find the root view
View root = someView.getRootView();*/

// Set the color
/*root.setBackgroundColor(color.darker_gray);*/
```