# ViewPager really slow on Samsung S4

Tags: android-viewpager, lag, samsung-touchwiz

SOLVED
Apparently you need to have the fragment drawables in respective drawable-xhdpi etc and not in drawable.

I have coded a ViewPager with three fragments that works flawlessly on LG G2, Sony Xperis S, Nexus4 and 5. But on the Samsung S4 it's impossible to swipe left/right without major lag, we have tested on 4 different S4's with the same resault.

```
public class ViewPagerMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

PageIndicator mIndicator;
int mViewPager;
private AutoScrollViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);


    ViewPagerMyPagerAdapter pageAdapter = new ViewPagerMyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (AutoScrollViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator = indicator;
    indicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    indicator.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    indicator.setRadius(5 * density);
    indicator.setPageColor(0x00000000);
    indicator.setFillColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    indicator.setStrokeColor(0xFFDE7900);
    indicator.setStrokeWidth(2 * density);

    viewPager.setInterval(3000);
    viewPager.startAutoScroll();
    viewPager.setScrollDurationFactor(12);
    viewPager.setCycle(true);

    TextView accept = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView notNow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView img = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terms);

    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                Uri.parse("http://www.123on.com/legal"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });

    accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           
            ActivityMain.contactPermission = true;
            Logging.log("viewPager:"+ActivityMain.contactPermission);
            ActivityMain.mActivityMainHandler.saveParams();


            if (!ActivityMain.userVerifyFlag){ // user didn't verify phone number

                finish();
                ActivityMain.verifyPhoneNumber();

            } else {

                Logging.log("error: with verify flag true without permission true.");
            }
        }
    });


    notNow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();
        }

    });

}    

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    viewPager.stopAutoScroll();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    viewPager.startAutoScroll();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

    }
```

and

```
public class ViewPagerMyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements OnPageChangeListener {

private List<Fragment> fragments;

public ViewPagerMyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(new ViewPagerFragmentOne());
    fragments.add(new ViewPagerFragmentTwo());
    fragments.add(new ViewPagerFragmentThree());
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I am starting to suspect that Samsung have some wicked problem in their framwork.

SOLVED

I re-sized the png's in code instead of xml.

Thanks
/Gekn