# how to install this background?

Tags: android

I have a background

[image]

is not a simple color I do not know how to set the background of your application

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the image to be repeated?

Comment: In which view(component) you want to set this image as back ground.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2706944/1278748

Comment: set this image into your layout background...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to display image in background and repeat it put this code in `drawable` folder:
`bg.xml`

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

and then simply apply this to your root view:
`android:background="@drawable/bg"`

Answer (score 1):

(1) Put your background image (e.g. my_image_name.png) in `res/drawable` folder.
*Hint: you can have different resolution images for different device densities (hdpi, mdpi) -- just place same name PNGs in the appropriate `res/drawable-xxx` folders.*

(2) To get the tiled look-and-feel, create a `res/drawable/my_back.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:src="@drawable/my_image_name"
      android:tileMode="repeat" />
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

(3) Next, create a new layout, e.g. `res/layout/main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/my_back" >

<!-- add your elements here -->

</FrameLayout>
```

(4) Finally, use the newly created layout with the tiled background in your Activity:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [android:background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground) property.

You can define a [Drawable Resource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) using that image, and specify how you want it to tile and so forth in the XML for the drawable.