# How to have background images without swiping becoming unbearable?

Tags: android, performance

I have 4 fragments that look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/hg_nahrung"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="de.noahsofie.abnehmen.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

....

</RelativeLayout>
```

I assigned a background image to each as in `android:background="@drawable/hg_nahrung"`, `android:background="@drawable/hg_aufnahme"` etc.

What was a quick swipe before is now choppy. But the images are just 720 x 1280(the resolution of my device). How to have background images without horizontal swiping becoming unbearable? Vertical swiping works flawlessly.

Changing png to smaller jpg did not help either.

EDIT: Here is the solution: [android background image slows down app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269186/android-background-image-slows-down-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the images in res/drawable-nodpi rather than res/drawable so that it won't get scaled up