# Edit text response slowly in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

In my project i have 9 editext box one page and am set a background for all these things,am use font serif fonts.in that am going to edit through virtual keyboard.edit text shows only after few seconds how to am going to rectify tat problems..any one know help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the background is getting stretched, which Android isn't really good with performance-wise. Use a background color or shape instead of image, or [make the background repeat instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706944/832776).

Comment: thank u oleg.hav to set shape means that problem wil solved ah.

Comment: how to set back ground using background repeat

Comment: ??? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat/2706944#2706944