# How can some part of image be repeated

Tags: android, background, nine-patch

[image]

I'm android app beginner developer.

I made an 9-patch to use image like above.

Dotted line of image is not repeated only stretched.

[image]

I have to write text on the image like above.

How can some part of image be repeated ?

Please tell me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can do that. 9-path image only stretches some part of the image. One solution could be is to use 3 drawables. One being the left arrow, one being the right arrow and one being the center image that is to be repeated. Then you can repeat the center image with dotted line as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat) and [here](http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html).