# Android arrange layout with height as percentage

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am very new to android and practicing. I am trying to design a screen. which will contain a background image and a floating container with sliding menus. ( For more details please find the attached image )

My layout consists of a background image, a container with some icons which float at the bottom  but with some margin to the bottom ( see attached photo )

As best of my knowledge this can be achieved by arranging a "Relative Layout" at the bottom and place images in it. Is it correct ?

Also I would likes to add a repeating transparent image as the background of the floating div.

Please give me a good advise or point me to a good tutorial

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` and set the [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight%20layout_weight) as % in `xml`

As for the repeating background you can use [tileMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#attr_android:tileMode%20tileMode)

Example: Note that the weightSum is set to `100`, to indicate the total weight will be `100`. Having `layout_weight=10` will give it `10%` space allocation.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:tileMode="repeat" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can set `layout_weight=11` it will give 11% height. For its parent we need to set `weightSum=100` as shown in the example.

Comment: @ramesh add layout_gravity="bottom" and layout_marginBottom="20dp" to the root layout of the answer and put it in in FrameLayout. If hardcoded 20dp does not suit you and you really want 5% you can set the marginBottom by calculating the percents in code.

Comment: The general idea is correct but would `weight=10` mean that it would take 100 - 10 % of height (=90%)? The more weight the less space they have, right?

Comment: @Bakhshi notice that there's `weightSum` in the parent layout. The height will therefore be `<layout_weight>/<weightSum> = 10/100 = 10%`, not 90%.  If `weigthSum` is not specified, then `<layout_weight>` values will be normalized to 1 with its sibling views

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the new percent support library:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent

By doing something like this:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_heightPercent="11%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to divide height in percentage then you need a linear layout with orientation horizontal and add layout_weight for each item.

[linear layout guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement any Layout is ok. You can achieve this by Linear layout too.
If I understand your requirement right, then check this discussion.

[How to make android app's background image repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat)

Answer (score 0):

```
<view android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      class="net.zel.percentage.PercentageButton"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      customView:percentage_width="50"
      customView:percentage_height="50"

      />
```

so you can add the desired attributes in a library 
 
https://github.com/metrolog3005/percentage_view