# How to set a static transparent image of line throughout whole application pages in android?

Tags: android, android-theme

I want to make an application in that several pages or say activities are there..now i want to put a static image @top and left hand side throughout the whole application.means fix at that position ..So can any one please tell me how can i do that? thanx in advance

Comment: You can make a separate layout and than include in all Activities.

Comment: hi buddy check this one http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: @nilkash-friend i am not asking for action bar...the image i want to put is just a line on the top side having no action

Comment: @kamil-any reference links bro?

Comment: you can create a header layout in separate xml file and then `include` it in your all layout files :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for image in imageview

```
android:tileMode="repeat"
```

OR

Visit [How to make android app's background image repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat)