# Is there a way to repeat the image multiple times as tiles in android?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, drawing, gimp

I want to make a floor like effect using a single image in android, somethig lake the Tile effect in GIMP. For example have a square already on my app and then create an image that has that square a lot of thimes[so that it looks at the end something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Zna.png)

Comment: A tiled background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) and put an image in each element.

[Here's a tutorial](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) that explains the concept of how to use images. You can of course refer to the same image multiple times, and adjust the borders and spacing to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager as your layout.