# Android Splashscreen background repeat pattern

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to have this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3qUw.jpg) repeated as the background of my splashscreen.
This is my **splashscreen.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_background_blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tileMode="repeat"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_splash_logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but the tile `android:tileMode="repeat"` seem to be ignored and the image is stretched to the aspect ratio of the screen.

**Edit:**

the `android:tileMode="repeat"` works for the activity background, but I am trying to archieve this on the splashscreen.
The`android:gravity="center"` doesnt seem to make any difference.

The *real* layout of my activity is irrelevant, since it never gets used I guess.
Here the code of my **SplashActivity.java**:

```
package de.ranellstudios.creactivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I connected the **splashscreen.xml** with my SplashActivity by adding a new theme to my **styles.xml**:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
</style>
```

and this

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

to my **manifest**.

I am just trying to make the image I linked at the top repeat in the background of my splashscreen instead of beeing stretched to the screen size.
Any ideas?

**-----**

Somehow it seems to work now, sorry for the inconvenience and thanks your your help. the code above is now correct.

Comment: provide your layout where you are adding this item please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make android app's background image repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat)

Comment: <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_background_blue"         
 android:tileMode="repeat" />

Comment: @YamenNassif I provided everything relevant now, I think.

Comment: @akhilesh0707I provided more information since the `android:tileMode="repeat"` doesnt seem to work. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not using `<layer-list>` in your drawable. try this code instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/ic_background_blue"
            android:tileMode="repeat"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_splash_logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**EDIT:** Checked the image that you provided and its resolution seems to be **too big** (2000 x 2000). Possible solutions are scaling the image down manually or make the image background programmatically.